# Django 1.9.2 "reverse" error during password reset attempt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-email

My app sits on Django 1.9.2 and Django REST Framework 3.3.2, with a single page app on the front-end. I must admit I'm new to Django but the docs are unmatched.

I'm trying to implement a custom PasswordResetForm view. My strategy is as follow:

1. User uses on a front-end form that `POST`s data (`email` string) to an API endpoint (`api/v1/password/reset`) when she wants to reset her password.
2. If email is found in DB, send an email and return a successful response.

For part 1, here's the relevant code:

```
# urls.py

url(r'^api/v1/password/reset/?$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password-reset-link')
```

-

```
# views.py

class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use DRF serializer to validate data.
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        # Ensure data is valid before proceeding.
        if serializer.is_valid() == False:
            return Response('error': serializer.errors, 'message': 'Error while attempting to reset password'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        else:
            # Ensure the user exists.
            existing_user = get_user_model().objects.filter(
                email=serializer.validated_data.get('email')
            )

            if not existing_user:
                return Response({'error': {'code': 'email_not_in_db'}}, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # Validated data fed to a child class of PasswordResetForm.
        form = UserForgotPasswordForm(serializer.validated_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ + '../../')), 'templates/registration/password_reset_email.html')

            try:
                # Save form, effectively attempting to trigger mail sending. 
                # Unfortunately an exception gets thrown!
                form.save(from_email='no-reply@abc.xyz', email_template_name=path, request=request)

                return Response({'message': 'Password reset request sent'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'error': str(e), 'message': 'Error while attempting to reset password'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

-

```
# forms.py

class UserForgotPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

-

```
# my_app/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html

{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password-reset-link' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% endautoescape %}
```

-

But I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'password-reset-link' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'MTI1', 'token': '4g9-f370fd6ee48d90a40b67'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/v1/password/reset/?$']
```

Any idea why? What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the url in your html you are passing a `token` and a `uidb64`:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password-reset-link' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

However, in your actual url, you do not reference the `token` or `uidb64`:

```
url(r'^api/v1/password/reset/?$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password-reset-link')
```

I would recommend changing your url to:

```
url(r'^api/v1/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password-reset-link')
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL named `password-reset-link` doesn't support the keyword arguments `uidb64` and `token` that you're sending it. Those keyword arguments aren't just extra data, they need to match somewhere in the URL pattern.

According to the error, your URL pattern is:

```
api/v1/password/reset/?$
```

In order to support what you want you'd need to put two [named arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) called `<uidb64>` and `<token>`. For example:

```
api/v1/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<token>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$
```

You'll have to adjust your regex to support the uidb64 and token formats.